# Liferay 7.4 circular dependency detected by gradle

Tags: gradle, liferay, liferay-7.4

I want to use multiple projects in Liferay 7.4 and am facing a circular dependency issue:

- Project A depends on Project B and
- Project B depends on Project A.

When we add these dependencies in build.gradle it shows a circular dependency error in the build.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to resolve circular dependencies is to extract a third module, typically an API module with just interfaces (maybe some utility classes), and have both existing modules depend on *it* rather than on each other.

Another (less popular) option is to merge both projects into one. Quite brute force, but technically solves the same problem.